# Cannot calculate combining equations

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, analysis

I am a graduate student and have researched security field.

I read the paper now and have some questions.

(Paper title : Enhanced Two-Factor Authentication and Key Agreement Using Dynamic Identities in Wireless Sensor Networks, In Section 4.1.)

Just simple question.

This paper calculates combining equations (1)-(5). However, I cannot understand why the result of calculation it is.

[image: equations 1-5]

Please let me know why the result is calculated.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write $$\lvert 2Pr[E_0]-1\rvert = \lvert 2Pr[E_0] - 2Pr[E_1] + 2Pr[E_1] - 2Pr[E_2] + 2Pr[E_2]- 2Pr[E_3] + 2Pr[E_3]- 1\rvert $$

Comment: Thank you for your help! I resolve this problem!! Thx :D!!